# Layer 3 Switch IP Problem on Packet Tracer

Tags: switch, vlan, ip, layer3

I set up a network. It contains vlans. I assigned devices ip addresses from different subnets. I have 2 layer 3 switches to communicate them. I assigned switches ip addresses from different subnet. I assigned ip addresses to vlan 1 of switches and i used vlan 1 of layer 3 switches as default gateway for the switches. The default gateway of switches is 172.16.0.30. When i connect to 172.16.0.30 by ssh, i connect to the layer 3 switch which is on left. My question is that: How i can connect other layer 3 swith ? How can i design that network properly ? The ip addresses of layer 3 switches are the same, that's a problem.
[image]

First Layer 3 Switch:

```
layer3-1#sh running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3936 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname layer3-1
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
!
!
!
username cisco password 0 cisco
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 1
ip domain-name domainswitch
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 2 mode desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 2 mode desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.16.0.30 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 000d.bd97.0501
 ip address 172.16.0.94 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan11
 mac-address 000d.bd97.0502
 ip address 172.16.0.126 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan12
 mac-address 000d.bd97.0503
 ip address 172.16.0.190 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan13
 mac-address 000d.bd97.0504
 ip address 172.16.0.158 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan14
 mac-address 000d.bd97.0505
 ip address 172.16.0.62 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
logging trap debugging
logging 172.16.0.164
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 1
 login local
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
line vty 2 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Second Layer 3 Switch

```
layer3-2#sh running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 4112 bytes
!
version 12.2(37)SE1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname layer3-2
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip routing
!
!
!
!
username cisco password 0 cisco
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip ssh version 1
ip domain-name domainswitch
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 1 mode desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 2 mode desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol pagp
 channel-group 2 mode desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.16.0.30 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 0050.0f79.3601
 ip address 172.16.0.94 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan11
 mac-address 0050.0f79.3602
 ip address 172.16.0.126 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan12
 mac-address 0050.0f79.3603
 ip address 172.16.0.190 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan13
 mac-address 0050.0f79.3604
 ip address 172.16.0.158 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
interface Vlan14
 mac-address 0050.0f79.3605
 ip address 172.16.0.62 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 172.16.0.161
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 1
 login local
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
line vty 2 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: We cannot simply guess what you did wrong. Please edit your question to add the device configurations (as text, using the `{}` preformatted option). Don't forget to name the ports.

Comment: As it seems, you‘ve configure SVIs but you haven‘t actually *created* the VLANs (`vlan x`).

Comment: i have created vlans on whole switches on the network

Comment: Not in the configs you‘ve posted above.

Comment: i have created, sh configuration command does not show me them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same IP addresses on both switches.  This is an **invalid** configuration.  Each interface needs a unique IP address.  If you need one gateway address for your devices, consider using a First Hop Resolution Protocol (FHRP), such as HSRP or VRRP.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @shiva13 Please don't forget accepting a valid answer to your question or it will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.